# Regex to match string that isn't a specific number?

Tags: regex

I have a tab-separated file that looks like this:

```
Something    1    Text...
Something    2    Text...
Something    2001 Text...
Something    1    Text
```

I want to match all lines that do not have 1 in the second to last column. So I tried this:

```
\t[^1][^\t]*\t[^\t]*$
```

But for some reason this does not work. Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: So what must be the result for your example? only the second line or the second and the third lines? What language/tool do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\S+\s+(?!.*1).*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hY1bT6/1)

Or else if you want `1` to be a complete word then use:

```
/^\S+\s+(?!.*\b1\b).*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/hY1bT6/2)

---

**EDIT:**

**To check for presence of `1` in last 2 columns only:**

```
/\t(?!.*1)\S+\t+\S+$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/hY1bT6/5)

Answer (score 1):

You regex `\t[^1][^\t]*\t[^\t]*$` does not work because it matches a tab, then *any character other than `1`, 1 time*, then 0 or more characters other than tabs, a tab, and 0 or more characters other  than a tab before the end of line (if you are using `m` mode).

I suggest reading everything in the first column, then a tab, and then set a check so that we do not have "1":

```
^[^\t]*\t(?!.*1).*$
```

Pay attention to the multiline `m` flag.

Here is [my demo](https://regex101.com/r/qK4zL8/1)

**EDIT:**

If you need to only make sure there is no `1` in the last 2 columns, use this regex:

```
^.*(?!.*1)[^\t]+\t[^\t]+$
```

EXPANATION:

- `^` - Start of line
- `.*` - Consume any characters from the start
- `(?!.*1)` - Set a check for `1` - it should not appear before the end of line from here!
- `[^\t]+` 1 or more characters other than a tab
- `\t` -  a tab
- `[^\t]+` - 1 or more characters other than a tab
- `$` - End of line.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG8jF5/1)

Comment: I should have been clear. I only want to read the last two columns. The `Something` is many columns and it would be easier to not explicitly read them.

Comment: And what about `1`? You want to get the last 2 columns if they do not contain `1`?

Comment: The regex in the answer you accepted [will not accept spaces inside the last 2 columns](https://regex101.com/r/nA3gM6/1). Mine [will](https://regex101.com/r/nA3gM6/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
/^[^\t]*\t((?!1).)*$/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL7zV6/2)

`(?!1)` is a negative look ahead that match any character that doesn't followed by 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match only lines without the character 1 from the second column until the end of the line, you can use this pattern:

```
^[^\t]*\t[^1]*$
```